# How to find all A s and B s such that AB=constant

Tags: matlab, equation, equation-solving

I have two numbers `a` and `b` such that `a*a*b=constant`. How can I find all `a`s and `b`s which satisfies this equation?

Can I have a graph for example for `a` versus `b`?

Actually, I am looking for a relationship between `a` and `b`, as an example an equation for their graph mentioned before.

Comment: There are an infinite number of solutions to this.  For any given `a` (other than 0), you have `b = constant / a^2`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a maths (algebra) question, rather than an explicit programming issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let `c` be the constant, then

```
a*a*b=c
```

We find an explicit solution for `b(a)` by

```
b = c / (a^2)
```

Now we can easily plot `b` vs. `a`. E.g. for `c=1` :

1. Specify which points for `a` you want to plot. E.g. `a = -2:0.1:2`
2. Calculate `b`: `b = c ./ (a.^2);`
3. Plot b vs. a: `plot(a,b);`

All together:

```
c = 1;
a = -2:0.1:2;
b = c ./ (a.^2);
plot(a,b);
```

[image: plot]